# Why is request.app not set in page handler?

Tags: node.js, express, request

i'm just trying to build some CRUD app with nodejs and express. To mok the database that should keep the data i just create an array at app level. Then I want to access this array in the handlers for the different pages.

Now the problem is, that the property app of the request object is not set when a handler is called.

Here the code i use:

```
var express = require("express");
var morgan = require("morgan");

var app =  express();

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.locals.dataStore = [{test: "bla"}];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Behold The MEVN Stack!'
    });
});

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log("request.app = " + JSON.stringify(req.app));    
    res.json("get data");
});

app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json("create data");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Running this code and calling the page from the browser produces this output

```
listening on 4000
request.app = undefined
GET /data 200 10 - 8.572 ms
```

Here some further info about my system:

```
OS: Win10 64
Node: v12.13.0
Express: 4.17.1
```

Since i found no other question about this problem, i assume that i'm doing something wrong. Any hint to solve the problem will be wellcome.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards
Gregor

Update:

I followed Alexis advice and changed my code. Nevertheless it does not work.

Here the new code:

```
/// index.js
var express = require("express");
var morgan = require("morgan");

var app =  express();

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.locals.dataStore = [{test: "bla"}];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Behold The MEVN Stack!'
    });
});

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log("request.app = " + JSON.stringify(req.app));    
    res.json("get data");
});

app.get('/test', require("./test.js"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
}); 

/// test.js
module.exports = function (req, res) {
    console.log("test.request.app = " + JSON.stringify(req.app));    
    res.send("get test");
  }
```

And the output after calling the according urls in my browser:

```
listening on 4000
test.request.app = undefined
GET /test 200 8 - 4.707 ms
GET /favicon.ico 404 150 - 1.358 ms
request.app = undefined
GET /data 304 - - 0.678 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `.app` you have to create a module that just exports a middleware function and require() it in your main file like this:

```
// index.js
app.get('/data', require('./mymiddleware.js'))

// mymiddleware.js
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  console.log("request.app = " + JSON.stringify(req.app));    
  res.json("get data");
}
```

[Here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) is the official documentation from Express

Comment: Ok, but what is the real difference between creating and requiring a modul and just passing a function to app.get?

Comment: I am not sure actually, the official docs do not mention something about that so I guess thats the API they designed.

Comment: As far as i understand the process of requiring a module, the export is just a defined format to declare the modules functionality. If export is set to function then require returns a function. Or is there some additional magic?

Comment: Thats tottaly true, I really don't know how this works as I meantioned before, all I know is that in order to get your code done you should follow this pattern.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll try it out the way you proposed later this afternoon, even though i don't understand the difference between the two ways. A little unsatisfying, but thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved as i'm able to access the global array in both ways using the correct / complete property path "req.app.locals.dataStore".

But the there remains one question:

Why req.app is shown as undefined when passed to JSON.stringify?

Any hint to the reason why would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards 
Gregor